# carousel muestra todos los slides Angular 5

Tags: bootstrap, angular, angular5, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy intentando meter un carousel en angular 5 y es un infierno (para mí). He creado un componente para mostrar el carousel, pero me muestra todos los slides (uno bajo el otro y superpuestos por la parte inferior) y todo el texto en la parte inferior superpuesto entre si.

El componente tiene este código:

```
    <div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="carouselDashboard" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselDashboard" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselDashboard" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselDashboard" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Este es el Slide #1</h3>
            <p>Contenido a introducir</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/city/2" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Este es el Slide #2</h3>
              <p>Contenido a introducir</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/city/1" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Este es el Slide #3</h3>
              <p>Contenido a introducir</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Controles -->
      <a href="carouselDashboard" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" arial-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
      </a>
      <a href="carouselDashboard" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" arial-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y en el index.html he metido estas 3 directivas:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

¿Se os ocurre que puede ser?

Comment: Probaste puniendo los Scripts en la parte de `angular-cli.json`? En el index suele no funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar, y tampoco se soluciona, sigue igual.

Comment: Los Styles también? Te fijaste en consola(F12) si le aplica los estilos correspondientes?

Comment: En la consola de Firefox me dice "[WDS] Disconnected" y en IE "SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script". Si lo dejo como estaba también muestra los mismos errores

Comment: Por lo que he visto, el problema está en el <link rel"stylesheet"...>. He probado con una versión anterior (3.3.7) y me funciona bien, por lo que imagino que el problema viene de la versión.